# file never fully downloaded

Tags: java, android, http, file, download

I am trying to download/resume file. Resume seems to work, but whole download brings the problem. After executing this code testfile is **5242845**. But it should be **5242880**! I opened this two files in the hex editor and figured out that testfile missing some bytes at the end (begining is okay). This is the code:

```
                String url = "http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip";

                String DESTINATION_PATH = "/sdcard/testfile";

                URLConnection connection;

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                File file = new File(DESTINATION_PATH);

                if (file.exists()) {
                    downloaded = (int) file.length();
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (file.length()) + "-");
                }
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = (downloaded == 0) ? new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH) : new FileOutputStream(DESTINATION_PATH, true);
                BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);
                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                int x = 0;
                int i = 0;
                int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();

                while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                    i++;
                    bout.write(data, 0, x);
                    downloaded += x;
         }
```

I think that the problem is here `while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {`.

For example we have file 1030 bytes long. First write is good, `bout.write(data,0,1024);` but next time `while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {` gets -1, because 1030-1024=6 bytes left. And we are trying to write 1024 bytes! I know it should not be so, but it seems that it is how I said. How can I figure this? Thanks.

Comment: Always close all unmanaged resources in a finally block. This is true for all in- and output streams here.

For cascaded streams it is sufficient to call `close()` on the outer most wrapping stream.

Doing not...well you see here what can happen and that's not all ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bout.flush();
```

and/or

```
bout.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean? Where should I put this, and why it should help? Thanks.

Comment: The buffer of your `BufferedOutputStream` isn't written to the file, yet.

Comment: put it at the end of your writing to the stream.  When you close the output stream, it should flush automatically.  Since it's streamed and not written directly to the file, you need to flush the stream before exiting the program.

Comment: +1 for close()

Please make it more clear that it is sufficient to only call `close()` but it is not sufficient to only call `flush()`. This 'or' maybe a bit misleading. Something like `bout.flush(); bout.close();` or `bout.close()` looks better for me.

Comment: it's sufficient to call flush() only if your program exits afterwards because the OS will cleanup the file handles for you on program termination.  But its generally good practice to close your files when you are finished with them even if it is a simple utility program.

Comment: you should also make sure to call close from within a finally block

Comment: @Michael - Yes, you should always do your cleanup in a finally block, but make sure to catch any IOException thrown by close() inside your finally block too or it will lead to ambiguous behavior.

Comment: Ohh - stating that calling `flush()` only is sufficient is a big nono. Stating to rely on condition that the program exits afterwards is adventurously. Sorry, but that is not the way to do serious programming.

For catching exceptions inside finally block: Yes, in most cases you want that. But when not doing it there is no ambiguous behaviour. I think it is well defined. Let me know if I am wrong here.

Comment: Yes there is ambiguous behavior.  Let's say an exception is thrown, so your method will throw that exception.  However, in your finally block another exception is thrown, now, which exception will be thrown back to the caller?  The exception that caused the error or the exception thrown in the finally block.  NEVER allow a throw or return from a finally block.

Comment: It is well defined, not ambiguous. The exception of finally block is thrown. The exception of try-block is discarded. (Also called 'the lost exception' in some famous books.)

See section 11.3 http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html

To be clear: I am totally with you and your recommendation to never allow throwing exceptions from finally.

Comment: When I say ambiguous, I don't mean undefined.  Ambiguous in that when the user expects a certain exception to be thrown from the caller when a certain error occurs, actually a different one is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your BufferedOutputStream to ensure that all that is buffered is sent to the buffered OutputStream.

Answer (score -2):

google told me, there is a "available" method of bufferedinputstream, so you can write like 
(I´m not an java guru)

```
while (in.available() > 0) 
{
    x = in.read(data, 0, 1024);
    bout.write(data, 0, x);
}
```